# Does there exist a random variable $\xi$ and a constant $c \neq 0$ such that $\xi + c \stackrel{d}{=} \xi$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Does there exist a random variable $\xi$ and a constant $c \neq 0$ such that $\xi + c \stackrel{d}{=} \xi$?

For context, I'm re-reading Kallenberg and in Chapter 3, on page 49, in his proof of Lemma 3.20, he states (emphasis added):

> So $\xi + a \stackrel{d}{=} \xi + b$. **Iterating this relation, we
>   get $\xi + n(b-a) \stackrel{d}{=} \xi$ for arbitrary $N \in
>  \mathbb{Z}$**, which is impossible unless $a = b$.

It seems to me that the bolded part of the text is not necessary, unless there is a positive answer to my question.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this is needed to show that the distribution is periodic (at least after a certain minimum value of $\xi$), which is not possible, provided the periodic portion is non-zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such random variable $\xi$ and constant $c \neq 0$ so that $\xi$ and $\xi + c$ are distributed the same. Why? If these two random variables were distributed the same, then their CDF's (say $F_1$ and $F_2$) would also be the same. Now
$$
F_1(z) = P(\xi \leq z) = P(\xi + c \leq z + c) = F_2(z+c) = F_1(z+c).
$$
Therefore, the CDF is periodic with period $|c|$. But this can not happen since $\lim_{t \to -\infty} F_1(t)=0$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} F_1(t) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks! I realize now that Kallenberg iterating the relation $\xi + n(b-a) \stackrel{d}{=} \xi$ was just his short-hand for essentially the argument you were stating.